# How can I pass "number variable" in function as reference in python?

Tags: python-3.x, pass-by-reference, nested-function

For better understanding here is a example code.

```
num = 0


def func(num):
    num += 1

func(num)
print(num)
```

This code prints 0 but I want 1(incremented by func()), how can I do that?

How can I do that? Is it possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I pass a variable by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference)

Comment: I deliberately posted this question, because I couldn't find it somehow when I needed it. So I posted this with different title and link. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long story short, you can't just put number in function and expect it to be passed by reference.

In python...

- (act like) pass by value : whole numbers, strings or tuples
- (act like) pass by reference : python list

You should visit here for more info about "Pass(call) by Object Reference".

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/is-python-call-by-reference-or-call-by-value/

Comment: I know there is similar question and answer in here(stack overflow), but I couldn't find when I needed it. So I post similar question and answer with different title and link for more info. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In python, when you declare a variable inside a function, python treats it as a new variable. That means, any changes to that variable doesnt show up **Globally**.

To go through his, add `global` to the top.
Example:

```
num = 0

def func():
    global num
    num += 1

func()
print(num)
```

Output:

```
1
```

Comment: That is not true, python gets function parameter as "pass by object reference". Please check my answer on top.

Comment: @EricWhale Thank You for correction. Much Appreciated :)